# Row-wise find substrings from one column in other column (combine grepl, strsplit and *apply)

Tags: r, sapply, grepl

I want to know, whether a string in one column exists in a range of columns. The search column can contain several strings, separated by ", ". I call them "search terms". I don't care if one or several terms are found, but I need to know if there are duplicates. Here is some mock-data

```
df <- data.frame(
  a=c("a","b","c, d","d"), 
  b=c(NA, "k", NA,"k"), 
  c=c("c1","c2","c3","c4, c5"), 
  search_terms=c("a",NA,"c, a","a, c5"))
df

     a    b      c search_terms
1    a <NA>     c1            a
2    b    k     c2         <NA>
3 c, d <NA>     c3         c, a
4    d    k c4, c5        a, c5
```

What I would like as a result is:

```
  test
1 search term found in a_c
2 <NA>
3 search term found in a_c
4 search term found in a_c
```

explainer:

1. Search term "a" is in column a
2. There is no search term
3. Search term "c" is in column a
4. Search term "c5" is in column c

So its possible to search for a string in all substrings of the search column. The following code correctly identifies "c5" in row 4. But I fail to do it a rowwise match.

```
df %>% mutate(test=ifelse(sapply(strsplit(df$search_terms, ", "), 
                                 function(x) {any(x == "c5")}),
                          "search term found in a_c",NA)) %>%
  select(test)

                test
1               <NA>
2               <NA>
3               <NA>
4 search term found in a_c
```

I further manage to check the existence rowwise, but not when the input is a list of strings. This code correctly identifies the first match, but neither the third nor the fourth.

```
df %>% tidyr::unite(a_c,a:c, na.rm = TRUE, remove=F,sep = ',') %>% 
  mutate(test=ifelse(mapply(grepl, search_terms,a_c),
                      "search term found in a_c",NA))%>%
  select(test)

                      test
1 search term found in a_c
2                     <NA>
3                     <NA>
4                     <NA>
```

I hoped to combine the two along the following lines, but failed with `grepl` only taking the first element. So it correctly identifies the first and the third match, but fails to identify the match in row 4. So why does the `any`-command not work here, but in the first line of code?

```
df %>% tidyr::unite(a_c,a:c, na.rm = TRUE, remove=F,sep = ',') %>% 
  mutate(test=ifelse(apply(.,1,function(x) {
    sapply(strsplit(x["search_terms"],", "), function(y) {
      any(grepl(y,x["a_c"]))
      })
    }),"search_term in a_c",NA)
    ) %>%
  select(test)


                test
1 search term found in a_c
2               <NA>
3 search term found in a_c
4               <NA>

Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `test = ifelse(...)`.
ℹ argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 
2: Problem while computing `test = ifelse(...)`.
ℹ argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your expected output? What does "search in a_c" mean?

Comment: I editied the post for clarity. Basically, I would like to highlight rows, that contain any of the terms in the column "search_terms" in any of the columns a to c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an answer which now seems deleted. It didn't work as I wanted but gave some crucial insights for the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% tidyr::unite(a_c,a:c, na.rm = TRUE, remove=F,sep = ',') %>%
 mutate(test=ifelse(apply(.,1,function(x) {
   sapply(strsplit(x["search_terms"],", "), function(y) {
     any(sapply(y, function(z) grepl(z,x["a_c"])))
   })
 }),"search_term in a_c",NA)
 ) %>%
 select(test)
```

The thing is that strsplit returns a list and hence requires a `sapply` command within the `any` function. As I understand the functioning of those nested `*apply` commands:

1. `apply(.,…` makes sure the following `function(x)` is applied on every row of `df`
2. `sapply(strsplit(`applies `strsplit` and outputs the list of search terms. For every list of search terms, the `function(y)` is applied
3. `any(sapply(` applies the `grepl` function on every it of the list of search terms.

However, I don't understand the logic fully and have the impression there is an easier way to solve that, with less `*apply`-functions. I further could imagine that there could be a cleaner `tidyr`-approach. However, the function gives me the desired output (here, with a slightly more complex `df`).

```
df <- data.frame(
  a=c("a","b","c, d","d", "e"),
  b=c(NA, "x", NA,"y", NA),
  c=c("c1","c2","c3","c4, c5", "c5, c6"),
  search_terms=c("a",NA,"c, a","x", "l, c6"),stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
df %>% tidyr::unite(a_c,a:c, na.rm = TRUE, remove=F,sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(test=ifelse(apply(.,1,function(x) {
    sapply(strsplit(x["search_terms"],", "), function(y) {
      any(sapply(y, function(z) grepl(z,x["a_c"])))
    })
  }),"search_term in a_c",NA)
  ) %>%
  select(-a_c)

     a    b      c search_terms               test
1    a <NA>     c1            a search_term in a_c
2    b    x     c2         <NA>               <NA>
3 c, d <NA>     c3         c, a search_term in a_c
4    d    y c4, c5            x               <NA>
5    e <NA> c5, c6        l, c6 search_term in a_c
```